# SwiftUI: How to create a color menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I would like to create a menu like this one in SwiftUI or UIKit (although I don't know UIKit).
This is the best I managed to get. I am guessing it is using NavigationView and a Picker.
This is my code and I couldn't implement this menu.
Any help is much appreciated!

[What I want](https://ibb.co/9G9CcxP)
[What I have](https://ibb.co/CKGk16r)

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker(selection: $userData.colorIndex, label: Label("Choose Color", systemImage: "eyedropper").font(.headline))
                {
                    ForEach(0..<userData.colors.count) {
                        Label(userData.colorsNames[$0], systemImage: "circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(userData.colors[$0])
                    }
                }
             }
              .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
              .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
  }
```

Comment: Ignore the fact that it is in a modal (I don't want a modal). [Here](https://ibb.co/WcXGGj5)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what your problem is?  From the image it isn't clear

Comment: Edited the image of what I want to have. I tried to use a list in a list (with InsetGrouped list style) but xCode can't make it work. @Asperi. I have included my current code now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your .listStyle to InsetGroupedListStyle()

Or you could also create something similar without using List like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var tapped = 0
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
        VStack{
    VStack{
        ForEach(0..<12) { color in
            Button(action:{ tapped = color })
            {
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    Text("Color Label")
                        .frame(height: 25)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: tapped == color ? "checkmark" : "")
                        .padding(.trailing, 20)
                }.foregroundColor(Color.random)
                    if color < 11 {
                    Divider().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 130)
                        .padding(.leading, 50)
                    }
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50)
    .padding(.vertical)
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(15)
        Text("Note that the app may need to be restarted for tint changes to take effect everywhere.")
            .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular, design:. rounded))
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Forget to write that I did that and it works on the main settings page but not on the picker page.

Comment: Ah I see. See above code for possible alternative. I just noticed from above comments that you're attempting to use a list within a list. That might be what's causing the bug

Comment: You gave me an idea to use a ForEach with buttons instead of Picker. I will try that. Thanks.